# Preparing for Probability Exam

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am preparing for my first exam in Probability, which covers the axioms and set algebra, discrete probabilities, combinatorics/counting methods, law of total probability, and Bayes Theorem.

I am mostly concerned about combinatorics/counting methods, because I still do not have an intuition for how to do these types of problems, like "what is the probability a random bridge hand will give North 8 aces?" or "Prove that (2n choose n) = sum from k = 0 to n of [(n choose k)^2] ".

How can I better understand how to think about and set up problems of this kind?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. There are some general principles (e.g. decomposing events into simple pieces, etc.) that are necessary, and I'm sure you've encountered them, but other than those I really don't think there are any bona-fide shortcuts that really make your life much easier in this class of problems with any consistency.

I say this as a student of probability and as a teacher of advanced courses using this material: the best thing you can do, and perhaps the only useful thing you can do, is as many problems as you can stomach. Try to solve problems on your own, looking at solutions only to check your answers or when you're absolutely stuck. If you successfully solve a problem, consider whether there was another approach that might have worked; it is often the case in these kinds of problems that there are multiple disparate ways to approach them. If you get an answer wrong, puzzle through it until you know why you were wrong. Try to solve problems in creative ways, and if you get a wrong answer, figure out what the flaw in your logic was.

This question is essentially like: "How do I become a better basketball player?" And the only answer to that, of course, is to spend some time on the court.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Aaron on the point of practice makes perfect. But the more perfect your practice, the faster you get perfect. So here are just two tips on how to approach questions, rather than what to study. Best of luck!

**Visualisation:** I always visualise these problems using Venn diagrams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram. I think this is a good mental model for probability and a useful aid for developing the intuitions. The nice thing about these is that you get an immediate visual representation of the probability space. The entire space is the set of all possible events. A circle represents a restriciton on the events e.g. the entire space might represent all outcomes for weather. You might then draw a circle and say that its interior represents a rainy forecast. You could then draw another circle that doesn't intersect with this at all that's a sunny forecast, assuming rain and sun can never coincide (in this simplified universe). A cloudy forecast probably includes the circle for the rainy forecast, making the simple assumption that it's always cloudy when it's rainy. The size of the circles represents probability: bigger being more likely.

**Change of Perspective:** Often there's an "easy way" to do a probability question. Some questions are purposely designed with a particular mode of solution in mind. Sometimes it's easier to count the number of events satisfying some condition vs. the total number of events in a space & get probability that way. Sometimes it's easier to get the probability of a simple event & use standard laws to get the probability of a more complex event e.g. one coin flip has probability $\frac12$ so seven has probability $\frac1{2^7}$. The key thing I'm suggesting here is to change your perspective as soon as you feel stuck, and try the question a different way from scratch. You'll often find that the new approach just fits the question better.